# Google+ Sign out with Android API not removing default accounts

Tags: android, google-plus, googlesigninaccount

I am able to sign in perfectly. I am able to signout also.

But when I start Signin again it does not ask me to choose account and automatically login with the same user which I signed in.

```
 private void signOutFromGplus() {
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {

        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();

    }
}

I also tried with revoke access. But did not work for me.
```

Comment: Make sure you have multiple users added.

Comment: @jaydroider 
 
I am getting Account Picker first time when I login but not second time.

Answer (score 0):

You can Use `AccountPicker` For This For Ref. Visit
[AccountPicker](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/AccountPicker#public-method-summary)

Comment: I am getting Account Picker first time when I login but not second time. So i do not think so this is the solution for this question.